# Binary Search Symbol Table

Tags: algorithms

Hi I'm attempting to self teach myself from Algorithms (Sedgewick) and ran across the following problem:

```
3.1.15: Assume that searches are 1,000 times more frequent 
than insertions for a BinarySearchST client. Estimate the 
percentage of the total time that is devoted to insertions, 
when the number of searches is 10^3, 10^6, and 10^9.
```

As stated in the problem Searches (S) = 1000 * Inserts (I)

- $S = 10^3 \to I = 1$
- $S = 10^6 \to I = 10^3$
- $S = 10^9 \to I = 10^6$

At this point in the book we are using simple arrays and linked lists to back symbol table (not efficient hash maps, trees, etc). This would mean searches take ~log2(N) time and insertions take ~N/2 time (assuming a uniform distribution on where inserts are placed).

Am I correct in calculating the % of insert to search time would approximately be:

$\frac{Inserts \times N/2}{Searches \times \log_2(N)}$

Using $Searches = 10^3 \times Inserts$ this reduces to

$\frac{N/2}{(10^3 \times log_2(N)}$

This would mean the percentage depends heavily on the initial size of the symbol table and is not a steady percentage that we can use to answer the question.

Any suggestions for what I am overlooking, should I be making an assumption about the initial size of the table?

Answer (score 1):

In computation, time consume depends deeply on the algorithm we choose. Since the search time consumes `log2(N)` and insertion  time consumes `N/2`, the insertion time increases sharply as compared to the search time. The only thing is that they depend on `size of the symbol table`, not the `initial size` because insertion and search time depend on the actual size of data set.

The chart below shows Percentage of Insertion Time over Search Time in your case.

[image]